# How can we implement dynamic query in sql CTE?

Tags: sql

How can we implement dynamic query in sql CTE?

Comment: [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) - this is more than unclear and seriously *cannot* be answered ....

Comment: what do you want..? dynamic query in cte ..? ask clearly

Comment: And why do you want to do it? What's the problem you're trying to solve? School assignment or just somebody said "implement dynamic query in sql CTE"?

Answer (score 0):

Implement dynamic query with CTE as

```
Declare @query Varchar(100)
Set @query = 'Select * From TableName'

Declare @Result Varchar(200)
Set @Result = ';With T As (' + @query + ') Select * From T'
Exec(@Result)
```

Comment: That's a very product specific answer. Note that no database is specified!